# Importing the same module twice because of the Shared Service

Tags: angular, typescript, import, module, export

What happens if I have the following scenario in the main module of my Angular application?

On the app.module.ts I import the module TranslateModule with forRoot() to configure it and make it available to all the application. In the shared.module.ts I export that module so that other modules can use it. In the shared.module.ts I also export services, so I create the forRoot() method and I import it into the app.module.ts.

This way I am importing TranslateModule twice. One directly in the app.module.ts with forRoot form and another one through the shared.module.ts. Is there a problem in doing this? If it exists, how can it be solved?

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ComponentsModule,
    DashboardModule,
    OtherModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    SharedModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

shared.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [CounterService]
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above approach should work fine. There won't be any issues in doing as above.

Once your **`app.module.ts`** configured with ngx-translate you can implement on other modules using shared.module as mentioned in ngx-translate repository, then you don’t need to worry about importing TranslateModule everytime. You only need to add this in your shared.module:

Read more on **[`this.`](https://medium.com/@lopesgon/translate-angular-4-with-ngx-translate-and-multiple-modules-7d9f0252f139)**

Comment: But it is necessary to import the TranslateModule into other modules that make use of the pipe translate. That's why I create the SharedModule, to import it into other modules.

Comment: sorry i did not realise that its TranslateModule.

Comment: Doing the SharedModule.forRoot () would be importing the TranslateModule again into the app.module.ts. Nothing happens to do that, right? Is that what you mean, there's no problem? Thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: yes exactly, read this article https://medium.com/@lopesgon/translate-angular-4-with-ngx-translate-and-multiple-modules-7d9f0252f139

Comment: Thank you. I understand that. But what I was referring to is whether importing the SharedModule in the app.module.ts may cause some problem. If I ask, it's because the app.module.ts is already importing the TranslateModule and the SharedModule imports it again. therefore in the app.module.ts it would not be loading the TranslateModule twice? It is not a specific question of ngx-translate since it can be extrapolated to any other module.

Comment: no it wont be an issue, check this sample repo https://github.com/sajeetharan/angular_web